# How to pass arguments to Google signIn in NextJS backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to create a role based google signIn in a nextJs 13 app which uses next-auth such that it calls 2 different Tables to create the user based their role.

I'm using mongodb/mongoose for DB.
The model for user is :

```
import mongoose, { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Email is required"],
    unique: [true, "Email already exists"],
    index: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Username is required"],
    match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "Username is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  userType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["typeA", "typeB"],
    required: [true, "User type is required"],
  },
});

const typeASchema = new Schema({
  typeA: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  other1: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "other_table1",
  }],
});

const typeBSchema = new Schema({
  typeB: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  other2: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "other_table2",
  }],
});

const User = models.User || model("User", userSchema);
const TypeA= models.TypeA || User.discriminator("TypeA", typeASchema);
const TypeB= models.TypeB || User.discriminator("TypeB", typeBSchema);

export { User, TypeA, TypeB};
```

Then in my /app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js, I define :

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { connectToDB } from '@/utils/database';
import {User, TypeA, TypeB} from '@/models/user';

function getRandomAvatarURL() {
  
}

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        })
    ],
    
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session }) {
                const sessionUser = await User.findOne({
                email: session.user.email
            })    
            session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();   
            session.user.image = sessionUser.image; 
            return session;
    
        },
          
        async signIn({ profile, userType}) {

            try {
                await connectToDB();

                // check if a user already exists
                const userExists = await User.findOne({
                    email: profile.email
                });
                
                // if not, create user and add to db
                if(!userExists) {
                    
                    const name = profile.name.split(" ");
                    const firstName = name[0] || ".";
                    const lastName = name.slice(1).join(" ") || ".";
                    const username = `${firstName}${lastName}`.replace(/\s/g, "");
                    
                    if (userType === "typeA"){
                        await TypeA.create({
                            email: profile.email,
                            username: username,
                            image: getRandomAvatarURL(),
                            userType: "typeA",
                        })
                    } else if (userType === "typeB"){
                        await TypeB.create({
                            email: profile.email,
                            username: username,
                            image: getRandomAvatarURL(),
                            userType: "typeB",
                        })
                    }
                }   
                
                return true;
    
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
                if (error.code === 11000){
                    console.log("Unique constraint violation error! Username already Exists!")
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    },

})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

In my Nav component I call the function like:

```
//imports
const Nav = () => {

// other code ...

const handleSignin = async(providerId, userType) => {
    console.log('provider.id:', providerId); // returns correctly
    console.log('userType:', userType); //returns correctly
    await signIn(providerId, { callbackUrl: "/dashboard"}, {credentials:{userType: userType}});
  }

//...

return(
    //....
    {providers &&
                Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (              
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    key={provider.name}
                    onClick={() => handleSignin(provider.id, "refree")}
                  >
                    <Image src="/assets/icons/signin.svg" width={20} height={20} className="rounded-none" alt="signin" />
                  </button>
                ))}
);
};
export default Nav;
```

I tried all the possible combinations for front end and backend, some of which are:

```
Frontend:

const handleSignin = async(providerId, userType) => {
    await signIn(providerId, { callbackUrl: "/dashboard"}, {credentials:{userType: userType}});
  }

const handleSignin = async(providerId, userType) => {
    await signIn(providerId, { callbackUrl: "/dashboard"}, {credentials:userType});

const handleSignin = async(providerId, userType) => {
    await signIn(providerId, { callbackUrl: "/dashboard"}, {userType: userType});
  }
const handleSignin = async(providerId, userType) => {
    await signIn(providerId, {userType: userType, callbackUrl: "/dashboard"});
  }

Backend:
async signIn({ profile, userType}) {
            try {
                await connectToDB();
                console.log(userType)

async signIn({ profile, credentials}) {
            try {
                await connectToDB();
                console.log(credentials)
```

It always returns undefined. I can't seem to capture the arguments passed from frontend to backend.
Any help or pointer is deeply appreciated.
The flow works when instead of passing userType argument I simply try to create the user of any one type on signIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument of `signIn` in nextauth, `authorizationParams`, is passed to the provider(google), not to the `signIn` callback.
You can make a custom provider and get the `userType` from the `user` of the `signIn` callback as follows:

```js
providers: [
    {
      id: "googleUserA",
      name: "GoogleUserA",
      type: "oauth",
      wellKnown: "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      authorization: { params: { scope: "openid email profile" } },
      idToken: true,
      checks: ["pkce", "state"],
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture,
          userType: "userA",
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    },
    {
      id: "googleUserB",
      name: "GoogleUserB",
      type: "oauth",
      wellKnown: "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      authorization: { params: { scope: "openid email profile" } },
      idToken: true,
      checks: ["pkce", "state"],
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture,
          userType: "userB",
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    },
  ],
  callbacks: {
    signIn: async ({ user, profile }) => {
      console.log(user.userType); // userA or userB
      ...
```

And FrontEnd will be like...

```js
signIn("googleUserA", { callbackUrl: "/dashboard" });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I create two different providers, it creates 2 different signIn buttons and on each one I get Error 400: access blocked, redirect_uri_mismatch. It doesn't work even if I add to redirect_uri in google console.

When I change the id : 'googleTypeA' to 'google' It works again but dosen't solve the purpose. I even tried making 2 providers with same id and different names and different userType but it dosen't work either.

Comment: @Saksham I wrote redirect url `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/googleUserA`, `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/googleUserB` and It works fine.
`redirect_uri_mismatch` error seems to happen when I sign in to another provider without sign out in the session.

Comment: Let me try by clearing cache/cookies and also on a different browser.

Comment: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4094#discussioncomment-2275173 I founded another solution... I hope it could help.

Comment: It works perfectly now after clearing the cache. Thank you so much for your prompt response @r4bb1t